# How to lengthen the short pulse of a turn signal?

Tags: led, capacitor, resistors

I am trying to upgrade my motorcycle with LED turn signals. The issue is with the particular light I am using and I believe I can solve it with a simple circuit addition. Please excuse any incorrect terms or diagrams, I am not well versed in this.

The issue is that there is a delay between power to the unit and the first blink. I need to lengthen the pulse of the turn signal to the LED. The voltage of the system is 12 V with about 500 mA of current.

If I used a 12 V, 10 μF capacitor in line, would this lengthen the pulse? I believe I would want to use a resistor after the capacitor, but I am a bit lost on what the correct values would be, or if this is even in the right direction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmHtEX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is it not the case that your flasher unit is seeing a lower current draw than expected so it is giving the "bulb-failure" indication of a shorter pulse or faster pulse rate? Your capacitor plan won't work. It blocks DC is indicated in the capacitor symbol by the air-gap between the plates. I think the usual fix is to put a resistive load in parallel with the LEDs to increase the current draw.

Comment: your question belongs at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/